# Understanding of some assembly lines

Tags: assembly

i have the following assembly lines:

```
....
LEA   EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[0x404212]
MOV   DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-0x3CC], EAX
PUSH  DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-0x3CC]
...
...
...
LEA   EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[0x404213]
MOV   DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-0x3D0], EAX
PUSH  DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-0x3D0]
...
...
```

So, I asked myself how I can that piece of code translate into a higher language like C? Or a pseudo C language?

But, for the the two blocks I have the following:

```
 UNKNOWNTYPE *eax_pointer_1;     //points to 00404212
 UNKNOWNTYPE *eax_pointer_2;     //points to 00404213
```

In ollydbg, I see that at the address 00404212 there is the following line :

```
ADD BYTE PTR DS:[EAX], DH
```

and at the address 00404213, there is:

```
XOR BYTE PTR DS:[EAX], AL
```

So my question would be : Is that a correct transformation? Have you some ideas how I can the instructions at **00404212** and **00404213** make part of my transformation into a pseudo-C language?

Comment: If you are sure these pointers point to a function (and not data), then your `UNKNOWNTYPE *` is a [function pointer](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html). To "make them part" of the entire code, convert the pointed-to instructions to a separate function as well.

Comment: ok, thx for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

> In ollydbg, I see that at the address `00404212` there is the
>   following line:
>
> ```
> ADD BYTE PTR DS:[EAX], DH
> ```
>
> And, at the address `00404213`, there is:
>
> ```
> XOR BYTE PTR DS:[EAX], AL
> ```

I dont think those are code, rather variables, are they in a code/execute section ?

Comment: No, they are not in a code/execute section. I only jump to that two addresses´ by right-clicking in ollydbg and then "Go To -> Expression"

Comment: Well, that invalidates my earlier comment. Examine the data at that point to guess the type of the pointer.

Comment: these two lines are data segment where arguments are pointing to, its abslutly useless to translate em into asm instructions !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the address of something (maybe an array element) is being taken and that is being used to set up call frame for later use.  Something *very* roughly like:

```
void f(void){
  void *x = &someMemory;
  void *y = &someMemory2;

  g(y,x);
}
```

caveat lector.